# Windows port opening

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, firewall, telnet

I had a problem with opening port between my host (windows 7) and a virtual box (windows xp) system.

On my host win7 system, I added a port from the inbound rule (port 777) under the firewall advance settings' exception tab. I also added the same port under the firewall exception from the virtual box (winxp) system. Now, when I attempted to do this from my host win 7 system:

telnet ip_add_of_winxp_vbox 777

and vice versa (from the virtual box winxp system):

telnet ip_add_of_host_pc 777

I was not able to get connected.

On my host machine (the win7) I had apache (xampp) installed so in my winxp system from the virtual box, I attempted:

telnet ip_add_of_host_pc 80

using port 80, I was able to get a response. But using other ports (port 777 and others), I cannot really connect. Can you help me out of here guys?

PS: I can ping both ways however but just telnet-ting a specific custom created port doesn't work. Both systems were connected on the same gateway.

Comment: What app are you running on port 777?  Just opening a hole in the firewall doesn't open the port on the machine.  Go open a cmd prompt and type "netstat -ano | find '777' " and see if it's open.  Unless of course you set apache to listen on port 777

Comment: thanks Jason. but it does not actually appeared from the netstat -ano.. I am attempting to open a port for testing on my python program.. any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't see it when you run the netstat -an command then your python script is failing.  regardless of your firewall if it doesn't show up with the netstat command it's not open.  Check your python script.

Comment: Perhaps you need to open the port in Windows' firewall. [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=windows+firewall+open+port&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=) some resources.

Comment: Maybe you can solve your networking problem by [enabling the logging of packets](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Network_tips) on the guest or host side.

Answer (score 0):

Both the OS's are seems to be in a single physical machine...one is on virtual machine and another on physical machine on the same system(Laptop)...

So try different ports for diffrent OS's...

I mean try 777 for windows 7 and 778 for xp in virtual box it may resolve the issue...

Comment: Isn't the port of the VM NATted anyway?